# HTML5 validation does not trigger when fields are not accesible

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form with multiple fields, and I need to scroll 10-15 fields until the submit button. I want to check if the form is valid or not via jquery. If the first field of my form is required and I click on the submit button the field borders are going red but the message is not displayed. If I remove all the required fields from the top and just add the last fields as required the message is displayed. If I resize the browser to be able to see the first field when press the submit the validation message is displayed. Does this function (reportValidity) work with not accessible fields?

```js
$('form').each(function() {
  var $form = $(this);
  $form.find(':submit').on({
    'mousedown': function(e) {
      var form = $(this).closest('form')[0];
      if (form.checkValidity()) {} else {
        form.reportValidity();
      }
    },
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="test">
    <label>Email:
      <input name=email type=text required title="enter your email">
    </label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <label>Email:
      <input name=email type=text required title="enter your email">
    </label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <label>Email:
      <input name=email type=text required title="enter your email">
    </label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <input type=submit>

</form>
```

Comment: Hidden fields don't get submitted to the server, so their validity isn't checked.

Comment: But these fields aren't invisible, they're just scrolled out of view? That shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: The validation messages are displayed next to the correponding form field. So if the form is scrolled out of view, you won't be able to see the message. If you want something better, you'll need to use third-party validation, like jquery-validate.

Comment: Yes, these fields are not invisible, are just scrolled out of view, but the problem is when the submit process is trigger the html5 validation is displayed, but not the same behaviour with reportValidity()

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: i added the fiddle, sorry for indentation is a quick one

Comment: I see it now. It scrolls to the invalid field, but doesn't highlight it, show the validation message, or give it focus like it does if the field is visible when you click the submit button.

Comment: This looks like a Chrome bug. Firefox and Safari don't have the problem. There's probably nothing you can do in your code, other than using JavaScript validity reporting instead of the built-in `reportValidity()`.

Comment: @Barmar, using the "e.preventDefault()" before reportValidity() solve the issue, i'm not sure if this prevent default is a good solution to solve it. What do you think ?

Comment: I think it should be OK. Which raises the question of why you need to call `reportValidity()` yourself -- the browser should do it automatically when the form is submitting. It's usually only needed of you're disabling normal form submission, e.g. using AJAX instead.

Comment: You can post that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, but the scenario is because i used invisible captcha, and if the form is valid check capcha, if is not , just return the form errors.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by adding event.preventDefault() before the reportValidity() call.